# How to get comments by post ID?

Tags: query, comments

I have this custom post query to list all the posts within a specific category.  For example I have this:

```
$args = array('cat' => 'home','post_type' => 'post'));
$post_obj = new WP_Query($args);
while($post_obj->have_posts() ) : $post_obj->the_post();
 // do stuff here
endwhile;
```

So for this page I would like to show the list of posts but also the accompanying comments.  I am only showing maximum 2 comments for each post.

Is there a built in function to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `get_comments`. [Function Reference/get comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

```
$args = array('cat' => 'home','post_type' => 'post'));
$post_obj = new WP_Query($args);
while($post_obj->have_posts() ) : $post_obj->the_post();
    //display comments
    $comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID,
        'number' => '2' ));
    foreach($comments as $comment) {
        //format comments
    }
endwhile;
```